# Arithmetics upon hashes

Tags: android

Dynamic brain PIN code authentication.
Here is new blind method of PIN-like authentication:
So we have a pinpad like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
* 0 #
```

for initial PIN config we use pattern say like "Y", so our PIN is 1358, it sha256-hashed and stored in persistent memory.
Then we doing authentication but not usual, like entering exactly matched pin 1358 , that could be viewed by third party, but we have a randomly scrambled pinpad:

```
5 7 6
2 3 1
4 0 9
* 8 #
```

and here our "Y" pattern is 5360 , but for blinding third party we summing this digits in brain and take modulo, so our input is 4, and that answer should authenticate us.

So what the problem: our system stores only sha256 hash of initial PIN pattern 1358 and it should somehow map a scrambled pinpad on initial pattern and calc the sum of digits upon hashed value.
I have found such things like homomorphic calculations and snarks, but seems it is not what we need here, could someone help with arithmetic rules (and framework) used to calc on hashed values?

Stronger PIN authentication

Answer (score -1):

Hashes or checksums, on which you perform arithmetic which maps to arithmetic on the source data, are unlikely to be cryptographic hashes.  (SHA256 is a cryptographic hash function).

Such operations do exist for many checksums.

If you could perform such arithmetic on SHA256, you would have broken SHA256.

See:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance